# Get all ManyToManyField objects from a related ForeignKey

Tags: django

**Goal**: List of projects and for each project all members of that project

I've been struggling with this for a while now; I have three models, as shown below (simplified versions of them):

```
class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Workstream(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name='email address',
        max_length=255,
        unique=True,
    )
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

**What I want:** to show an overview of each project, including a list of people on the project.

I was playing around a bit in the html template and came up with this (but this is not what I am looking for):

```
{% for project in projects %}
    {{project.name}} <br>
    {% for workstream in project.workstream_set.all %}
        {{workstream.members.all}}
    {% endfor %} <br><br>
{% endfor %}
```

The problem with the above is that users can be in multiple workstreams and therefore show up multiple times if this is the case.

A related question I have if is it is possible to get all users related to a project without having the addition for loop for workstream, I have only added this now because I did not find a way to do this directly.

**EDIT:**

Based on given answers I have changed views.py to:

```
projects = Project.objects.order_by('-created_date')

for project in projects:
    project_members = User.objects.filter(workstream__project__name=project.name)
```

I have also added related_name to the workstream model and updated the html template to:

```
{% for project in projects %}
    {{project.name}} <br>
    {{project_members}}<br>
{% endfor %}
```

Unfortunately it shows duplicates in persons now (one user is in two workstreams on a project) and the user/member list for all projects in the loop is the same, why does the loop in view.py not seem to work?

Answer (score 0):

If you call `.distinct()` in your query you can eliminate duplicates.
[docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/)

Add this in `Workstream` model

```
members = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name = 'workstream')
```

in your `views.py`

```
projects=Projects.objects.all()
for project in projects:
    users = User.objects.filter(workstream__project__name=project.name)
```

Try this, if this didn't work, please let me know

Comment: Where would I add this? In the view I only have added projects now (projects = Project.objects.order_by('-created_date')). I'm not sure where I would implement distinct in the parts mentioned above (in question)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! The problem is that I cannot filter on 1 project in my view, the page I'm trying to create should be an overview of all projects, and then list for each project who its members are

Comment: This will work, loop through all your project objects, and filter with `workstream__project__name` will give you all the users of that project.

Comment: The loop does not seem to work for some reason (user/member list for all projects are the same) and there still is the issue of duplicates. Any idea of how to fix this? (see edited question)

Comment: `User.objects.filter(workstream__project__name=project.name).distinct()` will eliminate duplicates.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221103/discussion-between-agus-mathew-and-caesar).